# JMeter - how to use dynamic variable in a HTTP request path

Tags: jmeter

I am wondering how I can use a dynamic variable in the Path field of a HTTP request . I am able to use User Defined Variables, but they are static, I need to use a variable that extracts some unpredictable value from the response of a previous HTTP request. I.e. the URL in the below scenario resolves literally to /this/and/that.jspx?param1=${testvar} , so you can see ${testvar} is not being substituted. How do I get ${testvar}, a variable created during regex extraction in a previous HTTP Request, to be substituted?

[image]

FYI I am using JMeter 2.11 and upgrading may not be an option (corporate policies... )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) resolution/substitution works normally no matter of JMeter version, I can think of 2 possible reasons:

1. You're looking into wrong place. You should be inspecting `Request` tab of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener in order to see the actual URL

   [image]

   [image]
2. Your `${testvar}` variable is not defined, i.e. Regular Expression Extractor fails to extract the required value. You can double check it using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script):

   [image]